# Renaming all files in a directory with a numerical sequence based on time created

Tags: bash, files, rename, mv

I am trying to rename all files in a directory, for example, ~/folder/ contains(from newest to oldest):  apple.foo, pie.foo, cookie.foo, melon.foo

renaming them with a fixed prefix and a number of 001 being the **oldest** and increase up to 999:

> melon.foo >> object001.foo
>
> cookie.foo >> object002.foo
>
> pie.foo >> object003.foo
>
> apple.foo >> object004.foo

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Hint: Use `ls -rt` to list the files, and use a loop with an incrementing counter? Watch out for "weird" file names (e.g. containing spaces).

Comment: @NickD ... or newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```
counter=0

for name in $HOME/folder/*(.NDOm); do
    counter=$(( counter + 1 ))

    suffix=$name:e
    printf -v newname '%s/object%.3d%s' $name:h $counter ${suffix:+.$suffix}

    mv $name $newname
done
```

This iterates over all names of regular files in the `~/folder` directory, from the oldest to the newes by last-modified timestamp.  For each name, a new name is constructed using the directory part of the current name and a counter. The files are renamed into these new names (without confirmation and without checking for name collisions).

The `printf -v newname` call will "print" its output into the variable `newname`.  The `%.3d` format string will output a zero-filled integer in three positions (e.g. `001`, `023`, `109` etc.)  The `$name:h` parameter expansion will expand to the head/directory portion of the `$name` pathname (it's the same as `dirname "$name"`).

The `$name:e` will expand to the "extension" of the original filename (e.g. `foo` if the current file is `apple.foo`), and we store this in `suffix`.  With `${suffix:+.$suffix}` we prepend a dot to the filename extension if there is one.

The `.` in `(.NDOm)` at the end of the filename globbing pattern is a glob qualifier that makes the preceding globbing pattern match only regular files.  The `N` and `D` makes the pattern act as if `nullglob` and `dotglob` in the `bash` shell had been set (expand to nothing if there is no match, and include hidden names in the result).  The `Om` orders the matching names so that the oldest (least recently modified) file is sorted first.

If `zsh` is not your login shell, then this could be run as a script instead.

```
$ zsh ./this-script
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version written in `bash` with GNU utilities that doesn't require parsing `ls`, and will handle any legally named file (embedded spaces, punctuation, newlines, etc.)

```
#!/bin/bash
k=0                                               # start at the beginning
find *.foo -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" |           # list all the files with modification time
    sort -z |                                     # sort by increasing modification time
    cut -z -d' ' -f2- |                           # discard the time value leaving just the name
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file                 # now loop for each file...
    do
        ((++k))                                   # next count
        seq=$(printf "%03d" $k)                   # format the three-digit counter
        name="${file%.*}" ext="${file##*.}"       # split filename into name and extension
        echo will mv "$file" "$name.$seq.$ext"    # show what would happen without doing it
    done
```

Remove the `echo will` when you are ready for the `mv` command to execute.

Example

```
# preparation
for f in {melon,cookie,pie,apple}.foo; do touch "$f"; sleep 1; done

# list in order of modification time (oldest to newest)
ls -tr
melon.foo  cookie.foo  pie.foo  apple.foo

# run the script and observe the output
k=0; find *.foo -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -z | cut -z -d' ' -f2- | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ((++k)); seq=$(printf "%03d" $k); name="${file%.*}" ext="${file##*.}"; echo mv "$file" "$name.$seq.$ext"; done

will mv melon.foo melon.001.foo
will mv cookie.foo cookie.002.foo
will mv pie.foo pie.003.foo
will mv apple.foo apple.004.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the filenames do not contain spaces, tabs or newlines, using one-liner and `bash` and `awk` would be simple:

```
ls -rt | awk -F "." '{print  $0 " object" sprintf("%03d",NR)  "." $NF }' | xargs -L 1 mv
```

The `xargs -l` command execute `mv` for each line. Before executing command execute the following command and check that target and source file names are correct:

```
ls -rt | awk -F "." '{print  $0 " object" sprintf("%03d",NR)  "." $NF }'
```

should output something like:

```
melon.foo object001.foo
cookie.foo object002.foo
pie.foo object003.foo
apple.foo object004.foo
```

Comment: Hello, the second line to check the target and source worked, but the first line didn't work, with error: xargs: illegal option -- l
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]

Comment: @kira, please use `xargs -L 1 mv`  forget about the posix standard. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked mostly, although none of the files has empty space in their name, but some of my files seemed to have illegal characters, the ones that failed are those that starts with a minus sign ``-`` ,and I received the following errors:  mv: illegal option -- 2
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
mv: illegal option -- w
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory